# Adding images to pdf drastically increases the size, even when images are 72dpi and 300x300 pixels

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp to create a pdf document, however when I add images to the pdf, the file size goes up dramatically, even though I am compressing my images to 300x300 pixels and 72dpi resolution.  When I create a pdf without images, it is about 300kb which is great, but the second I add a few images at this resolution and size, it goes up to 5mb.  Up to 25 images can be added, which would make my pdf a ridiculous size.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I have placed my code for compressing my images below:

```
    //maxSize = 300x300 and mimetype can be either "image/png" or "image/jpg"
    public static Bitmap CompressImage(Image currentImage, string mimeType, Size maxSize)
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
        Encoder myEncoder;
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        // Create a Bitmap object based on a BMP file.
        myBitmap = new Bitmap(currentImage);

        if (currentImage.Width < maxSize.Width && currentImage.Height < maxSize.Height)
            return myBitmap;

        if (myBitmap.HorizontalResolution > 72.0f || myBitmap.VerticalResolution > 72.0f)
            myBitmap.SetResolution(72.0f, 72.0f);

        Size compressedImageSize = new Size();
        compressedImageSize = ResizeToBound(new Size(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height), maxSize);

        Bitmap compressedBitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmap, compressedImageSize);
        myBitmap.Dispose();

        // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(mimeType);

        // for the Quality parameter category.
        myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;

        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // Save the bitmap as a JPEG file with quality level 75.
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 75L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        compressedBitmap.Save(stream, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

        compressedBitmap.Dispose();
        compressedBitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

        return compressedBitmap;
    }
```

This is the GetEncoder helper function

```
    public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        mimeType = mimeType.ToLower();

        if (mimeType.Contains("jpg"))
            mimeType = mimeType.Replace("jpg", "jpeg");

        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the ResizeToBound helper function.

```
    public static Size ResizeToBound(Size image, Size boundingBox)
    {
        double widthScale = 0, heightScale = 0;
        if (image.Width != 0)
            widthScale = (double)boundingBox.Width / (double)image.Width;
        if (image.Height != 0)
            heightScale = (double)boundingBox.Height / (double)image.Height;

        double scale = Math.Min(widthScale, heightScale);

        Size result = new Size((int)(image.Width * scale),
                            (int)(image.Height * scale));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you could make an example PDF available that you have created, we could take a look and see what actually gets stored in the PDF and what takes up the space. That might point you in the right direction quicker.

Answer (score 0):

When you add JPEG images to PDF files, these JPEG images will normally be added as they are without any modification (normally the JPEG file is copied unaltered to the PDF file).

If PDFsharp can't get the original JPEG file, the image will be added using lossless compression.

You store the image in a `MemoryStream`, but then read it into a `Bitmap` again. Maybe this prevents PDFsharp from accessing the original JPEG data. Just a wild guess - no definite answer can be given with the code snippets you provide.

Creating temporary JPEG files and passing the filenames to PDFsharp would be slower, but should lead to much smaller files. Maybe this can also be done with MemoryStreams, but without seeing your code that actually adds images to the PDF, this is difficult to say.